# Mysql checking for avaliable time between opening times

Tags: php, mysql, timespan

I am desperate, I read many posts but couldn't quite find a solution...

I have a table called `reservations`.
In there I have 5 fields

```
ID(int)
room(TEXT)
date(DATE)
from(TIME)
to(TIME)
```

lets say in PHP I have 4 variables:

```
$room =      "sauna";
$date =      "2015-03-03";
$open_from = "09:00:00";
$open_to =   "15:00:00";
```

I don't know how to make this Query which tells me whether there is still time for use between the opening times or not

I read many threads but I couldn't find anything which has this exact thing.

All I need is a '0' or '1' as a return value so I can simply dynamically remove the "add reservation" button from the page if there's no time left where one could put in a reservation anyways...

Please help me :(

Sincerely
Depth

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to query the value of $`open_from` and `$open_to` in PHP with an `if` statement?

Comment: Do you mean something like fetching all the entries for a day then doing the work in php ? Hmm.. Didn't think about that...

How could I do do the time calculation in php then since I am working with true time formats..